# how do you calculate unemployment rate from wage rate?

Tags: macroeconomics

how do you calculate unemployment rate from wage rate?

Answer (score 1):

You cant. It may be possible to predict the unemployment level based on some type of regression analysis on the wage rate but there is no way to determine one from the other.